# Export data from mysql table row into an array format

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to output data from

- table : artists
- row : artist

into this format.
Artist Names can have special characters and there are over 16k of them.
It needs to be written to a file. called anything artist.php for example

```
$Artist = array(
    "Name from database",
    "Name from database",
    "Name from database",
    "Name from database",
    "Name from database"
);
```

ok sorry for not explaining. do this for ajax auto complete.. so i need to create a file with this array in it.

I have it working and outputting the way I need it just stuck on the how to say it all to a file after its done.

here is what I have

```
require_once('config.php'); 

$res = mysql_query("SELECT artist FROM artists");
$ids = array();
$NotAllowed = array("(", ")", "+", ".", "-", "$", "#", "'", "\"", "%",":", ",", "*", "\\", "/");
    echo '$aUsers = array('; echo "<br>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $ids[] = $row['artist'];
    $FixedArtist = str_replace($NotAllowed, " ", $row['artist']);
        echo "\""; echo $FixedArtist; echo "\","; echo "<br>";

}
    echo "\"Lastname\""; echo "<br>";
    echo ");";




    $FileToSaveTo = "ajax-search.php";
    $fp = fopen($FileToSaveTo,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
    fputs($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");
```

Comment: Some context, please?  Why are you doing this?  Beware of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Yes try to use PDO for reading results and export it in a separate artists.json file, it's cleaner

```
/*require_once('config.php'); 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT artist FROM artists");
$ids = array();
$NotAllowed = array("(", ")", "+", ".", "-", "$", "#", "'", "\"", "%",":", ",", "*", "\\", "/");
/*while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $ids[] = str_replace($NotAllowed, " ", $row['artist']);  
}*/

//PDO version
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT artist FROM artists");
$sth->execute();
$ids = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//replace not allowed chars here

file_put_contents('artists.json', json_encode($ids));
```

then ajax-search.php will load this file

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/myfile.php on line 5

Comment: try with your old mysql_* functions or with PDO

Comment: @user1804952 tell if your problem was solved, and please accept an answer :)